# How to know why HttpClient call doesn't return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest

I have the following code taken from here:http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

I've updated the BaseAddress and header URL part to mine. The full URL works as expected through the browser.

When I use the code below, the call is made and returned from Web API app. I can see this because the Web API app is running in debug mode. But nothing happens at the caller side after this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
```

The app seems to freeze. The UI is unresponsive.  I do have that code in a try/catch block but it doesn't hit the exception.

Is there a way to find out what is happening?

The app is called like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // TODO - Send HTTP requests
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the method executing this code? I would suspect a deadlock due to usage of `.Wait()` or `.Result`.

Comment: Did you try Fiddler?

Comment: I've updated the OP

Comment: have you tried specifying the whole URL when you make the request, instead of using the `BaseUrl` property?

Comment: can you debug callee? does it get hit? (do you have  a breakpoint there by any chance :)? )

Comment: Using the full URL doesn't make a difference. yes - there are breakpoints there.

Comment: You said "The UI is unresponsive.", but in your question you seem to call that from console app. Is that UI or console app after all?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This sounds a lot like the result you would get if you tried to run this code under a WinForms app, but you've posted bits and pieces indicating a console app.

Comment: It is a winforms app - MDI forms app. Why would that be any different than calling from a console app?

Comment: What happens if you call .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of .Wait()? Given the symptoms you have described, it would seem as though you aren't properly awaiting the return of the Task.

Comment: There is no .GetAwaiter().GetResult()  on HttpClient instance.

Comment: I found how to use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() and that worked. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

> The app seems to freeze. The UI is unresponsive.
>
> It is a winforms app - MDI forms app. Why would that be any different than calling from a console app?

You're seeing a [common deadlock issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog. In summary, by default `await` will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. In a UI thread, that "context" is a UI `SynchronizationContext`, so the code after the `await` will resume on that UI thread. (In a Console app, there is no "context", so the code after the `await` will resume on a thread pool thread).

The problem is that the calling code is calling `Task.Wait()`. This will **block** the UI thread until that `Task` completes. However, that `Task` represents the execution of the `async` method, and that method cannot complete until the UI thread is free. Thus, deadlock.